# Finding a point on a circle that makes a specific angle of incidence with a given point inside it?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, algebraic-geometry, circles

Suppose we have a circle of radius *r* centered at the origin, and we are given a point C$(x,y)$ inside the circle.

[image: circle]

Let $\theta_i$ be the angle of incidence of the line drawn from C. If we know $\theta_i$ (say, 23º) and C, how can we find the coordinates of P$(x,y)$, the point on the circle where the angle of incidence from C is $\theta_i$?

Edit 1: Oops, forgot to draw P in the circle. It's the point where the line meets the circle.

Comment: I haven't done the calculations so I'm posting this as a comment. This is the strategy: Let the point be P(x,y). Make two linear equations for the two lines OX and OP, then use the formula $$\tan \theta = \left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$$ (where m1 and m2 are the slopes of the lines) and solve for theta.

Comment: @Kartik The problem is that your unknowns are in the $m$s.

Comment: Just to clarify, you know only the coordinates of $C$, and the angle of incidence $\theta_i$, and you want to know the coordinates of $P$, the point where the "reflected" ray strikes the circle again (in this diagram, on the right side of the circle, just above the $x$-axis)?

Comment: No, I know $C$, and I want to find the point $P$ on the circle which has an angle of incidence of the given $θ_i$. The reflected ray is actually extraneous; apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

To find the points $P$ on a given circle $c$ of center $O$ and radius $R$, such that $\angle CPO=\alpha$ given, join $CO$ and from its midpoint $M$ draw the perpendicular bisector $r$. Let $A$ be a point on $r$ such that $\angle CAM=\alpha$ (that is $AM=CM/\tan\alpha$), then draw the circle $a$ having center at $A$ and passing through $O$ and $C$. The intersections between $a$ and the given circle $c$ are the required points, as well as the symmetric of those points with respect to line $OC$. In fact, if $P$ is one of such intersections, then $P$ lies on $a$ and $\angle CPO=(1/2)\angle CAO=\alpha$. Notice that we have no solutions for $OC<R\sin\alpha$ ($a$ contained in $c$), two solutions for $OC=R\sin\alpha$ ($a$ tangent to $c$) and four solutions for $OC>R\sin\alpha$ ($a$ secant to $c$).

If $x_C$, $y_C$ are the coordinates of $C$, then 
the coordinates of $A$ (or $A'$) are given by
$x_A={1\over2}(x_C\mp y_C/\tan\alpha)$, 
$y_A={1\over2}(y_C\pm x_C/\tan\alpha)$, 
and it is straightforward to get the coordinates of the intersection points:
$$
x_P={2R\sin^2\alpha\over t^2}
\left(
Rx_A\pm y_A\sqrt{{t^2\over\sin^2\alpha}-R^2}
\right),\ 
y_P={2R\sin^2\alpha\over t^2}
\left(
Ry_A\mp x_A\sqrt{{t^2\over\sin^2\alpha}-R^2}
\right),
$$
where $t=OC=\sqrt{x_C^2+y_C^2}$.

**Edit from Blue.** Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: @Blue Thanks a lot, the picture is perfect now!

Comment: @Aretino Very interesting diagram. Is it possible to construct a formula from given values (e.g. $O$, $C$, *r*, $\theta_i$) to find one of the coordinates of $P$?

Comment: I've just added some formulas: please check them before use.

Comment: Just to clarify: $R$ is the radius of the yellow circle, right?

Comment: Yes, of course: $R$ is the radius of the given circle. I forgot to mention it in my answer, now I'll add it.

Comment: And of course I hope the sense of the various $\pm$ is clear enough: one has two possible positions for point $A$, and for each choice of $A$ one has then two possible intersection points (if they exist, of course).

Comment: Yep I get it, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Hi @Aretino, I confused and can't quite understand how you derived your formula. Could you please explain in detail how you obtained it? Thank you so much.

Comment: What is you don't understand exactly?

Comment: Just to make clear: angle $\alpha$ in my answer is equal to angle $\theta_i$ in your question.

Comment: I don't understand how you solved for the formula you presented in your answer.

Comment: The equation of circle $c$ is $x^2+y^2=R^2$, while the equation of the circle centered at $A$ and having radius $OA$ is $(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2=x_A^2+y_A^2$. Solving the system of these two equations gives the stated result.

Comment: I'm sorry... I mean, the formula works in practice, but I'm completely lost as to how the formula came to be. If it doesn't inconvenience you too much, could you walk me through the working?

Comment: By subtracting those two equations in my comment above you get $2xx_A+2yy_A=R^2$. Solve this for $y$ and substitute into $x^2+y^2=R^2$, to obtain a quadratic equation in $x$: $$(x_A+y_A)^2x^2-R^2x_Ax+R^2(R^2/4-y_A^2)=0.$$ Solve for $x$ to get $$ x={R^2x_A\pm Ry_A\sqrt{4(x_A^2+y_A^2)-R^2}\over2(x_A^2+y_A^2)}.$$ Now substitute here the identity $$(x_A^2+y_A^2)={t^2\over 4\sin^2\alpha}$$ to obtain my formula for $x$. The formula for $y$ follows.

Comment: Where does $$(x_A^2+y_A^2)={t^2\over 4\sin^2\alpha}$$ come from?

Comment: We have: $x_A={1\over2}(x_C\mp y_C/\tan\alpha)$, so that  $x_A^2={1\over4}(x_C^2+y_C^2/\tan^2\alpha\mp x_C y_C/\tan\alpha)$, and in the same way: $y_A^2={1\over4}(y_C^2+x_C^2/\tan^2\alpha\pm x_Cy_C/\tan\alpha)$. By adding these together one gets:  $x_A^2+y_A^2={1\over4}(x_C^2+y_C^2)(1+1/\tan^2\alpha)$
and plugging here $x_C^2+y_C^2=t^2$ (by definition of $t$) and $(1+1/\tan^2\alpha)=1/\sin^2\alpha$ one obtains that result.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the center of the circle is the origin.  We have $P\cdot(P-C) = |P| |P-C| \cos\theta$, but $|P|=1$, so $P\cdot (P-C) = P\cdot P - P\cdot C$ (by linearity) $= 1-P\cdot C$ and this equation becomes $1-P\cdot C = |P-C|\cos\theta$; then squaring both sides and using $|v|^2=v\cdot v$, we get $(1-P\cdot C)^2 = \cos^2\theta (P-C)\cdot (P-C)$.  We can use linearity to expand the RHS again, getting $(1-P\cdot C)^2=\cos^2\theta(P\cdot P-2P\cdot C+C\cdot C) = \cos^2\theta (1+|C|^2-2P\cdot C)$.  This is a quadratic equation in $P\cdot C$, which you can solve to get that value (or values - I see no reason that the given point $P$ should be unique).

Finally, given the equations $P\cdot C=q$ (where $q$ is a calculated value from solving the quadratic above) and $P\cdot P=1$, there are presumably several ways to solve for $P$ but the simplest (to me) is to just set $P=(x,y)$ and note that $P\cdot C=q$ is a linear equation in $x$ and $y$, so we can use it to substitute one of $x,y$ for the other in $P\cdot P=1$ (which is just the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ of the circle), getting the final values of $x,y$.

Comment: $P$ is not unique in general, depending on whether $C$ is closer to the point of incidence than is the center of the circle, or further.  Or, possibly, it might not exist, if $C$ is to close to the center of the circle.

Comment: @BrianTung Yep, that makes sense to me. The conditions here, expanded out - I didn't actually plug in the full quadratic for $P\cdot C$ - should reflect those constraints.

Answer (score 1):

- Fom the figure below we can calculate:

$\cos(D)=\frac{a}{d}$.....(1)

$\cos(D+\theta)=\frac{a}{r}$ ..... (2)

(2) in (1) -> $\cos(D)=\frac{r\cos(D+\theta)}{d}$

$d=\frac{r\cos(D+\theta)}{\cos(D)}$ ........... (3)

- From [rules of triangle](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-sine-law.html) we deduce the following:

1-the big triangle:

$\frac{r}{\sin(e)}=\frac{B}{\sin\theta}$

$\sin(e)=\frac{r\sin\theta}{B}$.....(4)

$\frac{C}{sin(Y+y)}=\frac{C}{\sin(2\pi-e-\theta)}=\frac{C}{\sin(-e-\theta)}=-\frac{C}{\sin(e)\cos\theta+\cos(e)\sin\theta}=\frac{B}{\sin\theta}$

$C=-B\sin(e)cot\theta-B\cos(e)$....(5)

2- from right triangle:

$\frac{A}{\sin(e)}=\frac{B}{\sin(\pi-t)}$

$A\sin(t)=B\sin(e)$,

from (4): $A\sin(t)=B\frac{r\sin\theta}{B}=r\sin\theta$....(6)

$\frac{A}{\sin(e)}=\frac{C-d}{\sin(Y)}$

$\frac{A\sin(Y)}{C-d}=\sin(e)$

From (5), $\frac{A\sin(Y}{C-d}=\frac{A\sin(Y)}{-B\sin(e)\cot\theta-B\cos(e)-d}=\sin(e)$,

using (4),

$A\frac{sin(-Y)}{B\frac{r\sin\theta}{B}\cot\theta+B\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2\sin^2\theta}{B^2}}+d}=\frac{r\sin\theta}{B}$
...... (7)

3- From left triangle:

$\frac{A}{\sin(\theta)}=\frac{d}{\sin(y)}$

$\frac{A*\sin(y)}{d}=\sin\theta$ ..... (8)

---

[image]

- Knowing that $\sin(y)=\frac{a}{r}=\cos(D+\theta)$ ....(9)

(3),(9) in (8) -> $\frac{A*\cos(D+\theta)}{\frac{r\cos(D+\theta)}{\cos(D)}}=\sin\theta$

$\frac{A*\cos(D)}{r}=\sin\theta$ .... (10)

(3) in (7) ,

$A\frac{sin(-Y)}{B\frac{r\sin\theta}{B}\cot\theta+B\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2\sin^2\theta}{B^2}}+\frac{r\cos(D+\theta)}{\cos(D)}}=\frac{r\sin\theta}{B}$
...... (11)

(10) in (11)

$\frac{r\sin\theta}{\cos(D)} \frac{sin(-Y)}{B\frac{r\sin\theta}{B}\cot\theta+B\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2\sin^2\theta}{B^2}}+\frac{r\cos(D+\theta)}{\cos(D)}}=\frac{r\sin\theta}{B}$

$ {B}\frac{sin(-Y)}{{\cos(D)}{r\cos\theta}+{\cos(D)}\sqrt{B^2-{r^2\sin^2\theta}}+{r\cos(D+\theta)}}=1$

$\cos^2 D + \frac{{\left(\cos D\, \left(2\, r\, \mathrm{\cos}\!\left(\mathrm{\theta}\right) + \sqrt{B^2 - r^2\, {\mathrm{\sin}\!\left(\mathrm{\theta}\right)}^2}\right) - B\, \mathrm{\sin}\!\left(- Y\right)\right)}^2}{r^2\, {\mathrm{\sin}\!\left(\mathrm{\theta}\right)}^2} - 1=0$...(12)

with:

$x=cos(D)$

$a1=2*r*\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{B^2-(r^2*\sin(\theta)^2)}$

$a2=(B)*\sin(-Y)$

$a3=(r*\sin(\theta))^2$

**solutions:**

$x_1=\frac{\mathrm{a1}\, \mathrm{a2} + \mathrm{a3}\, \sqrt{\frac{{\mathrm{a1}}^2 - {\mathrm{a2}}^2 + \mathrm{a3}}{\mathrm{a3}}}}{{\mathrm{a1}}^2 + \mathrm{a3}}$

$x_2=\frac{\mathrm{a1}\, \mathrm{a2} - \mathrm{a3}\, \sqrt{\frac{{\mathrm{a1}}^2 - {\mathrm{a2}}^2 + \mathrm{a3}}{\mathrm{a3}}}}{{\mathrm{a1}}^2 + \mathrm{a3}}$

Comment: When typesetting try to use `\sin` instead of `sin` because it is easier on the eyes. Like $\sin(a)\cos(b)$ vs $sin(a) cos(b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q$ be the point of incidence. We can solve the triangle OCQ with sides $r$ and $|OC|$ and the angle $\theta$ by the sine law and find the angle $\angle{COP}$.
$$\sin(\angle OCQ)=\frac r{|OC|}\sin(\theta)\\
\angle COQ=\pi-\angle OCQ-\theta.$$

This gives the polar angle of $Q$ (knowing that of $C$).
The requested point $P$ has a polar angle equal to that of $Q$ minus the angle at the apex of an isosceles triangle, $\pi-2\theta$.